# Can't access multi dimensional associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
foreach ($cardSuits as $cardSuit) {
    $keyCardValues = array_keys($cardValues);
    foreach ($keyCardValues as $cardValue) {
        $deck[] = array( "cardValue" => $cardValue, "cardSuit" => $cardSuit);
        shuffle($deck);
    }
}

if ($deal == "Deal") {
shuffle($deck);
$cards1 = array_shift($deck);
$_SESSION['value'][] = $cards1;
```

I've tried:

```
echo "<br />" . $_SESSION['value']['cardValue'];
```

But it's giving me an undefined index error.  However, if I do a print_r, it works fine..
How do I echo it so the session can give me the $cardValue in the array?

Thanks

edit for print_r:

```
Array ( [value] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [cardValue] => nine [cardSuit] => hearts ) ) [cards] => Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 2 [2] => 10 [3] => 4 [4] => 3 [5] => 10 [6] => 5 [7] => 2 [8] => 10 [9] => 5 ) )
```

EDIT for echo print_r:

```
Array ( [value] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [cardValue] => nine [cardSuit] => diamonds ) ) [cards] => Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 3 [2] => 7 [3] => 10 [4] => 9 [5] => 11 [6] => 7 [7] => 10 [8] => 10 [9] => 5 ) )
```

Comment: Can you post the result of `echo print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: $_SESSION['value'] is array. Use foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `$cards1` is an array and that you are assigning this array to `$_SESSION['value'][]`, you want to access `cardValue` using the following:

```
echo "<br />" . $_SESSION['value'][0]['cardValue'];
```

Answer (score 1):

try

`echo "<br />" . $_SESSION['value'][0]['cardValue'];`

Comment: For earliest complete answer. @yay4programming, you missed the [0]

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
echo "<br />" . $_SESSION['value'][0]['cardValue'];
```

Array value is inside the index 0